# Is There A Way to Move Data Type Items to Multiple New Columns In R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a project that involves data for different professions across the US and right now I'm working on Auctioneers. One of the columns in my dataset lists each state and I'm wanting to take specific states from the state column and move them into newly created columns that specify  the region they reside in. So the New England states would go into a column titled as New England. Mid-Atlantic States would go into a Mid-Atlantic Column and so on.

I thought about using the mutate function but that didn't seem to work. I looked around online for solutions but I didn't find quite what I'm looking for. Is there a way this can be done either with the mutate function that I'm overlooking or maybe another way?

Thank you again!

I've created an example below to help make the explanations easier. Ideally I'm looking to take the states out of the "States" Column and place them into a new column, So Maine and Vermont would go into a "New_England" Column, Georgia and Florida would go into a column titled "South" and California and Washington would go into a "West_coast" column.

```
States <- c("Maine", "Georgia", "California", "Vermont", "Florida", "Washington")
Players <- c("1a", "1b", "2a", "2b", "3a", "3b")
Score <- c(15, 21, 8, 17, 12, 11)

data <- data.frame(States, Players, Score)
```

I hope this example helps! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Do you have some sort of list that maps each state name to a region? If you put that in a data.frame, you should be able to merge/join the data together and do the summary.

Comment: I do have an excel doc from an index project that my collogues worked on that matches states with a region. It's a completely different dataset and the states in that excel file are listed by a specific rank while the states in the project I'm working on are listed alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

```
region_mapping <- data.frame(
  States = c("Maine", "Georgia", "California", "Vermont", "Florida", "Washington"),
  Region = c("Mid Atlantic", "Southern", "West Coast", "New England", "Southern", "West Coast")
)

data_with_regions <- data %>%
  left_join(region_mapping, by = "States")

data_with_regions %>%
  group_by(Region)
```

I don't know if this the efficient method.
Is this the output you looked for:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   Region [4]
  States     Players Score Region      
  <chr>      <chr>   <dbl> <chr>       
1 Maine      1a         15 Mid Atlantic
2 Georgia    1b         21 Southern    
3 California 2a          8 West Coast  
4 Vermont    2b         17 New England 
5 Florida    3a         12 Southern    

6 Washington 3b         11 West Coast
```

From here you could `summarize` to know what happens in each region by using `group_by(Region)` if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Golem! That's not quite what I'm looking for. I did have a kind of apheny after reading your answer. The idea was simple and it got me closer but it's still not quite to what I want. I created new variables for each region and added the states to a new vector. Then using "$" I added each new variable to the dataframe. This solution got me closer to what I wanted but it ended up duplicating each state in the vector in order for the new variables to match the dimensions of the rest of the dataframe.

Comment: Here's the code I used: `New_England <- c("Maine", "Vermont")
South <- c("Georgia", "Florida")
West_Coast <- c("California", "Washington")

data$New_England <- New_England
data$South <- South
data$West_Coast <- West_Coast`